# ORDER BY SobjectType

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have the following query and want to sort on the Name of the SobjectType. As it is now the sort is not as expected. I am also displaying the results in a Visualforce page. How can I best retrieve the Name of the SobjectType for the sort by to show the proper alpha order.

```
public class RickDev_ProfilePermissionsController {
    public List<FieldPermissions> fldlist{get;set;}
   
    public RickDev_ProfilePermissionsController(){
       // query for profile object field permissions 
        this.fldlist = [SELECT SobjectType, Parent.Profile.Name, Field,PermissionsEdit,PermissionsRead, Id, ParentId, Parent.Name                                        
        FROM FieldPermissions 
        WHERE parentid in (select id from permissionset 
        where PermissionSet.Profile.Name = 'ME Business Control') ORDER BY SobjectType asc 
        ];           
    }       
}

    <apex:pageBlock title="ME Business Control profile field access">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!fldlist}" var="fld" columnsWidth="20%,20%,10%,10%,10%,10%,10%,10%">
            <apex:column headervalue="Profile" value="{!fld.Parent.Profile.Name}" />            
            <apex:column headervalue="Object" value="{!fld.SobjectType}" />                
            <apex:column headervalue="Field" value="{!fld.Field}" /> 
            <apex:column headervalue="Edit" value="{!fld.PermissionsEdit}" />
            <apex:column headervalue="Read" value="{!fld.PermissionsRead}" />
            <apex:column headervalue="ID" value="{!fld.Id}" />                  
            <apex:column headervalue="ParentName" value="{!fld.Parent.Name}" />
            <apex:column headervalue="ParentID" value="{!fld.ParentId}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it does this, it may be a bug of some sort. The solution for situations like this is to use a custom class to sort the data:

```
class Wrapper implements Comparable {
    FieldPermissions value;
    Wrapper(FieldPermissions value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public Integer compareTo(Object o) {
        Wrapper w = (Wrapper)o;
        return w.value.sobjectType == value.sObjectType? 0: 
            w.value.sObjectType > value.sObjectType? -1: 
            1;
    }
}
```

You can then populate a list of values:

```
Wrapper[] items = new Wrapper[0];
for(fieldpermissions p:[SELECT SobjectType, Parent.Profile.Name, ...]) {
    items.add(new Wrapper(p));
}
items.sort();
fldlist = new FieldPermissions[0];
for(Wrapper item: items) {
    fldlist.add(item.value);
}
```